# Convert VARRAY to text (for concatenation)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial, varray

I have a query that outputs a VARRAY:

```
select
    a.sdo_geom.sdo_elem_info
from
    (
    select
        sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (1 2,3 4)') as sdo_geom
    from
        dual
    ) a
```

In SQL Developer, the VARRAY gets output as text:

[image]

---

**Question:**

Similar to what SQL Developer does, is there a way to convert the VARRAY to text using SQL — so that I can concatenate the value in a string?

Example: (fails)

```
select
    'MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(' || a.sdo_geom.sdo_elem_info || ')'
from
    (
    select
      sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (1 2,3 4)') as sdo_geom
    from
      dual
    ) a

[Desired result: 'MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 2, 1)']

ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 37
```

---

Just a heads up:

DB<>FIDDLE doesn't seem to output VARRAYS correctly. It outputs an empty resultset, which can be confusing. [Return a value/row when selecting SDO_GEOMETRY](https://topanswers.xyz/databases?q=2008)

Comment: Here too, I'm curious about the actual business need for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listagg` in a subquery:

DBFiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=fa79482bb22501fd67fb2c498ff90bf9

```sql
select
    (select listagg(column_value,',') from table(a.sdo_geom.sdo_elem_info)) cc
from
    (
    select
        sdo_geometry('LINESTRING (1 2,3 4)') as sdo_geom
    from
        dual
    ) a
```

Comment: Char Col... :-D

Comment: For my notes, for other SDO_GEOMETRY object attributes, such as `.sdo_ordinates`, I need to investigate whether the ordinates get ordered correctly or not: 
 *"[I am not sure if your simplified query keeps the order of the ordinates. To be safe I would definitely use the ORDER BY clause of LISTAGG.](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/comment/16834549/#Comment_16834549)"*